# Routes for specific controllers

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api

In my Web API scenario, this (default) route works well for almost all my controllers.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and for a couple of my controllers, I want to have them mapped by their action name, like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**Background:**

Most of my controllers are to be mapped by default to GEE, POST, PUT and DELETE.
However, I reserve some "admin" controllers that perform operations, such as data initialization, cleanup and testing stuff. These controllers may have multiple methods that are excetude via GET, hence the second route.

If I use either of these routes, they work well, however, if I set both, I get one of two failures:

Default route first:

```
api/books/                -> OK
api/books/someGuidId      -> OK
api/admin/someAdminAction -> 500 Internal Server Error (multiple actions found)
api/test/sometestAction   -> 500 Internal Server Error (multiple actions found)
```

Action route first:

```
api/books/                -> OK
api/books/someGuidId      -> 404 Not Found (no action that matches "someGuidId")
api/admin/someAdminAction -> OK
api/test/sometestAction   -> OK
```

My question is: how can I have these routes working out at the same time?

[**EDIT**]

api/books/someGuidId is not an important call, I can live without it (via GET) however, POST, PUT and DELETE to same url will fail, wich is not acceptable.

Comment: I updated my answer, do You really need "id" param in "ActionRoute"?

Comment: see "Edit 2" in my answer, it will fix Your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the routs matter, so You should set more specific routs first:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ActionRoute",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultRoute",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

**Edit:**

**`Default` route first:**

```
api/books/
```

This url matchs the first pattern: api/{controller}/{id}.
Framework looks for `books` controller with `GET` (PUT,POST,DELETE) method, and finds it. This method is invoked with default `id` value.

```
api/admin/someAdminAction
```

This url also matchs the first pattern. (BTW, It doesn't matter how You name Your parameters in the route definition: `id` or `superParamName`, When Framework compares URL with routs it will look only for patterns and can not distinguish by param names.

The Framework will try to invoke `GET` (PUT,POST,DELETE) method of `admin` controller with `someAdminAction` id (Which, I suppose, is not a valid id value:)

**Similar thing You get when You define `Action` route first:**

```
api/books/
```

Matchs *`api/{controller}/{id}`*, id can be omitted, cause it was set to "optional".

```
api/books/someGuidId
```

Matchs *`api/{controller}/{action}/{id}`*, so, when Framework looks for `someGuidId` action method in `book` controller and it doesn't find it, it throws an exception. **404 Not Found (no action that matches "someGuidId")**

**Edit 2:**  I think, in case You will always pass `id` param for "Actions" and place "Actions" route first, You will not get any collisions. Try this.
If You need `id` param be optional in both cases, You can just remove it from both routs and pass it in a normal way via `?`(question mark).

One of this would fix Your routing problem.

Comment: I've tried both approaches, ActionRoute first and DefaultRoute first. Each of these approaches will fail in someway (see my question).
Is there any way to map ActionRoute  to specific controllers?

Comment: I figured that the problem might be something like what you explained, but +1 for detailed explanation! However, id does not fix the problem itself. As per your comment, yes, in action route I am comfortable taking out {id} parameter if I have to. However, I'd figure it would collide with default rout, would it not?

Comment: just interesting, what option have You picked: remove id, or question mark?

Comment: I guess both. Removed ids (but they can be still used via `?param=value`. This way I way I get two ways of calling same resource: `api/books/` (default route) and `api/books/get` (action route) will do the same.
I'm still testing and adapting my system, but your answer set me in the right track :) Thank you.