# How to control or change the URI to MVC4 Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an MVC4 Web API Application. I placed all of the APIController classes under Controllers/API and now I am creating MVC Controller classes in the Controllers/ folder.

I Add a controller named UserController specifying Read/Write with views using EntityFramework. This automatically generates a folder under /Views called Users. It contains the Create.cshtml, Delete.cshtml, Index.cshtml, etc. files.

Problem is that I want the URI of this User view to be /Admin/User/

Did I miss an opportunity to specify creating the view under the Admin/ folder? I tried copying the entire folder where I wanted it, but it isn't accessible that way. I delete the controller and view, then recreated the controller but I didn't see anyplace I could set that would cause the view to get created under Admin/.

How do I create the MVC controller, and autogenerate the CRUD pages under a specific Views folder?

**-- UPDATE --**

I added the route for Admin/. Here is my RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Administration",
            routeTemplate: "Admin/{controller}/{action}"
        ); 
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I don't know if it matters, but I have a MVC controller for Admin - it's called AdminController. Thinking it might be in the way, I changed `routeTemplate: "Admin/{controller}/{action}"` to `routeTemplate: "Admin1/{controller}/{action}"`, but it made no difference.

Here is the error I am seeing:

```
<!--  
[HttpException]: A public action method &#39;user&#39; was not found on controller &#39;MYPROJECT.Web.API.Controllers.AdminController&#39;.
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
 -->
```

After the CRUD pages are automatically generated there is a new folder created with the .cshtml files inside it. Except, it is created at `/Views/User/`. Is it ok that I move (drag/drop in VS) this /User/ folder so that it is located at `/Views/Admin/User/`? (If for no other reason but for organization).

Comment: I guess what you're looking for is URL Routing, Take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624181/Routing-Basics-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

Comment: You mean that even though I want all of my CRUD pages under my /Admin/ URI I have to create them in /Views/ instead of /Views/Admin/?

Comment: Excellent link btw. Thank you. Maybe what I missed pointing out is that I first created an empty MVC controller called AdminController. This gave me the /Admin/ URI on my web site. Now what I want is to autogenerate CRUD forms for each entity so they all are under /Admin/. Like /Admin/User/ or /Admin/Product/.

Comment: what you  mean is, you need uri like `Admin/User/Create` , `Admin/User/Delete`.. ?

Comment: Right. I don't know how else to do it. Seems practical to keep the Create, Delete, Index .cshtml files separate for each entity. /Admin/ will require authentication/authorization.

Answer (score 1):

If You want to change the URI You should register new route. Go to `WebApiConfig.cs` in `App_Start` folder. Here You register routes for `ApiControllers`. Add the following route above the default route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "SpecifyYourRoutName", // optional
    routeTemplate: "Admin/User/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "User" }
);
```

Now when You access `Admin/User/Create` You will hit `Create()` method of `User` controller.
If You want to pass some data in the URI like for instance `id` of the item to be deleted You just write: `Admin/User/Delete?1` and this will call `Delete(int id)` method of `User` controller and pass `1` as `id` to this method.

If You will have other controllers with similar URIs You can define Your route like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "SpecifyYourRoutName", // optional
    routeTemplate: "Admin/{controller}/{action}"
);
```

In this case You can query URIs like Admin/OtherControllerName/ActionOfThisController?param1=something1&param2=something2...

Comment: Aleksei, I guess I didn't expect to manually configure the URI. structure. I knew it was an option. I tried your second example, but config generates an error. I tried Routes.MapHttpRoute and just MapHttpRoute but they both generated errors also. I think the second example is what I need.

Comment: Don't have it working yet, but resolved the previous problem. Had to create the Register() routine to get the HttpConfiguration? I was trying to place that code above the Web API MapRoute code and it wasn't working. As for the problem now, I still can't browse to /Admin/User/ - 404 Not Found.

Comment: @rwkiii, of course You can't :) You should specify the action explicitly like  /Admin/User/Create. Otherwise, how do You expect the asp.net mvc routing mechanism to find out what action of Your "User" controller to call

Comment: I tried /Admin/User/Create also but got a 404 with it as well. I'm new to MVC, sorry. Was just thinking old school I guess - Index would come up by default. I did set it as the default action. But I think I know what might be wrong at this point. I have a controller called AdminController. There is an error that there is no method called User in AdminController. I created it because I thought that was how I got an /Admin/ folder in the first place. Now it seems to be in the way?

Comment: @rwkiii, did You placed my route above the default route? Because more specific routes should be placed first. I've answered a similar question already. Refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578749/routes-for-specific-controllers/18578918#18578918       If this will not help You please update Your question and provide all info about Your controllers and  routes so I (or other guys) can help You.

Comment: Aleksei, I updated my question with additional information. I see differences in some of the route examples. Sometimes RegisterRoutes is used. In your example that would not work since config.Routes.MapHttpRoute isn't passed. So I created a Register() routine that does pass the HttpConfiguration object. It would seem that these routes need to be added in the same routine as each other (according to your answer). Of course, I have these route configurations in separate routines. Could this be the issue?